# Ubuntu couldn't detect Nvidia GT 740M

Tags: nvidia, graphics, lenovo

I am using Lenovo Z500 running on Ubuntu 15.10, with the following VGA specifications:

```
VGA1: Intel HD 4000
VGA2: Geforce GT 740M
```

After running `lspci` command, it detects the Intel HD but couldn't detect the second graphical card `Nvidia`. The `lspci` output is as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

Also, I couldn't find the graphical card information using `lshw` command, the following is the output of this command:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:d3000000-d33fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

I am using the latest released BIOS (2013) from Lenovo corp and the graphical card mode in BIOS sets to `Switchable Graphics`.

Could any one please explain me what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting GT 740 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Before you install new drivers uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the long-lived branch by executing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

After switching to **NVIDIA** run **sudo lspci** again and the output shows your **NVIDIA GT 740 GPU**.

Note :

In case you use Ubuntu 15.10 there is no need to add the Proprietary GPU drivers repository (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa) - the drivers are already included in the Ubuntu repositories. If you had bumblebee installed before you have to remove it as well.

Comment: I am doing what you said. Let me test your answer :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Still lspci didn't list the `NVIDIA GT 740 GPU`.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher : Did you logout and back in after switching to nvidia ?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the system.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher : Try to change the BIOS settings from switchable graphics to nvidia graphics.

Comment: There is not option "nvidia graphics" in BIOS. Two options exist: 1. `UMA Graphics`, 2. `Switchable Graphics`

Comment: @HosseinMobasher : 1.) Please check whether Switchable Graphics is enabled - if not : please enable it. 2.) Please check whether NVIDIA X Server Settings - PRIME Profiles are set to "NVIDIA Performance Mode". 3.) Please copy the complete 'sudo lshw' output to a place from where it can be accessed and provide me with the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your PCI ID database use this command.

```
sudo update-pciids
```

then

```
sudo lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it and the output didn't changed. 
Output of `sudo update-pciids` is `Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2015-10-29 03:15:02` and output of `sudo lspci -nn | grep VGA` is `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)`

Comment: try this command `sudo nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader`

Comment: NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

I face similar situation and consulted an expert ,
looks like there are limitation about the match of graphical card
and compiler / cuda version support.
looks like my card is supported up to Ubuntu 13.04 so 15.10 is not
supporting it. In addition I suspect the g++ library on kernel does not fit
the kernel g++ that support cuda 6.0.37 for my card and cuda version cc1.0
that is supporten only until gcc/g++ version 4.8.x while ubuntu 15.10 kernel
use gcc/g++ 5.0.X version.

you might have been facing compatibility issue with your hardware that is not 
supposed to function properly on 15.10.

I have a similar problem my system construct is:

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: G96 [GeForce 9400 GT]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:30 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff

:~$ /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
Tue Nov  3 13:29:21 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.93     Driver Version: 340.93         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 9400 GT     On   | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
|  0%   50C   P12    N/A /  N/A |     57MiB /   511MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    :~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000641sv00001043sd00008296bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : G96 [GeForce 9400 GT]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-340-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
```

when I change the display to use onboard intel d type display cable output
the SMI module is not loaded and connamd "/usr/bin/nvidia-smi"
failes because it can not comunicate the driver.

mybe someone can help with a solution how to drive display from onboard intel 
graphics hardware ( i5 processor 4 threads) and yet keep the NVIDIA 340.96 driver loaded on kernel?